# Are there any good PHP based HTML filters available?

Tags: php, html, security, filtering

I am currently in a project with a PHP frontend. We're pretty concerned about security, because we'll have quite a lot of users and are an attractive target for hackers. Our users are able to submit HTML formatted content that is visible to other users later. This is a big problem because we're vulnerable for the whole set of XSS attacks. We're filtering as good as we can, but the variety of attack vectors is pretty big.

So, I'm searching for PHP based HTML sanitizing/filtering solutions. Commercial solutions are fine (even preferred). Currently we're using a modified HTML purifier, but we're not satisfied with the results.

What are some good libraries/tools that are capable of filtering malicious parts of HTML?

It is nice to have for example HTML5 awareness, which will become a security nightmare once it's available "in the wild".

**Update:**
We're doing an in-depth configuration of [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It looks like the older framework we used before was just not configuring it at all. Now the results look much better.

Comment: Any chance you can use a simplified markup language (like stackoverflow uses with Markdown) that allows **you** to decide what tags actually get presented?

Comment: Also, I think the fact that there are 6 votes for the question and no votes for any of the 5 answers (right now), reinforces the idea that there just aren't any good solutions to this problem with the HTML filtering approach.

Comment: We're in favor of using some simplified "markup" languages, but we can't control all possible incoming channels and some customers will use software that is either capable of html or plaintext and the chance to convince them and some stakeholder on our side that this is a usable approach is rather small :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## HTML Purifier project

Personally I have had very good results with the [HTML Purifier project](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

It is highly customizable and has a huge code base. The only issue is uploading the files to your server.

Are you sure you have not got a configuration issue with your installation? As the purifier should not let through any HTML tags at all if configured correctly.

**From the web site:**

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.
>   Tired of using BBCode due to the
>   current landscape of deficient or
>   insecure HTML filters? Have a
>   WYSIWYG editor but never been able to
>   use it? Looking    for high-quality,
>   standards-compliant, open-source
>   components for that    application
>   you're building? HTML Purifier is for
>   you!

I wrote an article about how to use the [HTML purifier library with CodeIgniter](http://logicflip.com/2009/05/using-html-purifier-in-code-igniter-to-clean-user-generated-content/) here.

Maybe it will help with giving it another try:

```
// load the config and overide defaults as necessary
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML', 'Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('HTML', 'AllowedElements', 'a,em,blockquote,p,strong,pre,code');
$config->set('HTML', 'AllowedAttributes', 'a.href,a.title');
$config->set('HTML', 'TidyLevel', 'light');
```

Comment: Just to note, the OP did say: "Currently we're using a **modified html purifier**, but **we're not satisfied with the results**."

Comment: It is strange that the HTML purifier is not working for the asker. I presume the config is set up wrong at some point.

Comment: It's possible that we can get around some of the problems by further configuration, but we had some cases where our penetration guys bypassed it. Currently html purifier is our best bet, but I was hoping to find another glory shiny solution here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) has an excellent XSS filter, you could rip it out of the system/libraries/Input.php file if you wanted it as a standalone function.

Comment: Hmm, I fear that this doesn't meet our non functional requirements on "foreign" code. Ripping code from another framework may be appreciated by the PM ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[kses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/) works well. You can easily specify which elements to allow and disallow, so making it ‘HTML5-aware’ would just be a matter of setting an array.

WordPress uses it, so I guess it’s pretty safe ;)

Comment: html 5 will be a little bit more tricky, as it will introduce for example attributes on closing tags etc. And the author states on the sourceforge page that he has no time to maintain the package, which is a deal breaker :-/

Answer (score 1):

I can really recommend [kses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/) for HTML filtering. Actually that's what wordpress uses. Its free and open source.

Comment: But it's not actively maintained :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use your current solution and add iframes with different base URLs to show the contents. Changing the base URL on the iframe will disable access from the internal JavaScript code to the main page. That is, if your URL is http://www.yoururl.com/thread/500
you can use it in the iframe to show content, something like: http//yoururl.com/thread/500/coment/1, http//yoururl.com/thread/500/coment/2.

The base URL you can set can be dependent on your DNS/host configuration.

It's not a solution to fix the problem but to jump it over, although it can be useful until you find something else.

Comment: That's not really an option due to several constraints. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this class before and had pretty decent success:
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2189.html

Comment: Looks like it's no longer maintained. Last release was 2005 and there have been many new exploits that are most likely not covered by this.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLPurifier probably works—but let me just say that the folder structure is over-complicated and pompous. Hundreds of lines of comments, a folder called "test", a license file, read-mes and info files, images, ANOTHER folder for smoketesting (which is downright abusive), extras, configs, benchmarks—and to top it all off, about 10 different CMS compatibility modes, testimonials on their website, full versions, lite versions, husky, mildly-chubby, down-syndrome and the full spectrum of politically correct programatical variations.